# Unity 5 ParseObject.GetQuery wont work

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, leaderboard

I've a problem loading scores from parse. There is 3 users with scores in database and I'm trying to hook them:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScores").OrderByDescending("Scrore");//.OrderBy("Nickname").ThenByDescending("Score").Limit(25);
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        results = t.Result;
        Debug.Log(results);
        foreach (ParseObject obj in results)
        {
            var score = obj.Get<string>("Score");
            Debug.Log(score);
        }
    });
```

First debug returns

> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[Parse.ParseObject]

The second is not execute at all, what is wrong?

Comment: The proper tag for Unity3D is unity3d.